# Not able to spy the pop-up window through Blueprism

Tags: popup, blueprism

I am trying to spy the pop-up window to click "OK" in the pop-up. But I am not able to proceed. As per my analysis, it seems I have to create a new object and then attach it to the main, but I don't know how to proceed with this.
Can anyone please help with the same.
Thanks

Comment: What pop up window?  Please remember, we cannot see what you see on your screen, so in order to help you need to be very clear about what you are trying to do, and what is not working...  Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

OK, where do you get this pop-up? When you use some kind of macro in excell? If so the simple change your code and dont show any msg like that.

If its something else then yes, you need to attaché BP to that popup and press OK to confirm or...

If it is a stable proces, that is allways running with the same configiuration on the screen(window size, windows placment on the screen) then you could try to "click" in the area that your popup window allways is shown.

Hope it helps.

RAFEL.